Polynomial $f(x)$ has positive coefficients and all roots as real. How many polynomials formed from terms of $f(x)$ also have only real roots?
Let
$$f(x)=a_n \ x^n+a_{n-1} \ x^{n-1}....+a_1 \ x+a_0$$
be a $n$-th degree polynomial with positive coefficients such that all of its roots are real. Choose any number terms from this expression ($a_nx^n$, $a_0$, etc, are called the "terms"), and define a polynomial by adding all these terms.
For example, the new polynomial $g(x)$ can be defined as,
$$g(x)=a_0+a_{n-5} \, x^{n-5}+a_2 \, x^2$$
$$g(x)=a_{n} \, x^{n}+a_{n-1} \, x^{n-1}+a_2 \, x^2$$
(These have been refered to as $sub-polys$ under the comments)
Now the question(s) are these:

How many such total chosen polynomials will have all of their roots real?


Can a solution even be formed to this problem


If a solution can be formed, does it depends on the roots, coefficients or some other information related to $f(x)$

If a solution can be formed and it depends on more information about the constants or anything else, please choose and specify such conditions.
I actually don't know if a solution can be formed. I sincerely apologise for not showing any of my work, because I am not getting any ideas and I am just a high school student. Thank you for your time.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

38th edition of this question!

Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477522/polynomial-fx-has-positive-coefficients-and-only-real-roots-how-many-polyno

@GerryMyerson: OP promised to stop making non-substantive (single-word! (the same word!)) edits to bump the question, but evidently just can't seem to resist. :) ... It's a shame that the recent $200$-point bounty didn't seem to attract more interest. ... Considering what seems to go into characterizing polys all of whose consecutive-term sub-polys have only real roots (see the Hutchinson result in my answer), devising a scheme to count generally how many CTSPs an arbitrary poly has seems more like a research project than a Math.SE task. Repeatedly bumping the question won't help w/that.

@Balaji: Please note that copying someone else's work without attribution (as you did by pasting much of my answer into your MathOverflow cross-post) is plagiarism. Don't do that!

It's a pity that the bounty was not started twelwe seconds later.

Consolidating and revising my comments into a partial answer ...
In concordance with Petter Brändén's paper "Unimodality, Log-Concavity, Real-Rootedness and Beyond" (PDF link via arxiv.org), suggested in a comment by @Nolord, I'll adopt the term "real-rooted" for a polynomial, each of whose roots is real.
Moreover, adjusting the stance in some assertions in my comments, I'll also adopt the convention that a (non-zero) constant polynomial is real-rooted. (After all, when a polynomial has no roots at all, it's vacuously true that any root it has is real.) This will keep me from having to sprinkle "non-constant" qualifiers throughout the discussion.
Preliminaries aside ...

As per the question, we're starting with a real-rooted polynomial $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k x^k \qquad a_k> 0 \tag1$$
and we're tasked with counting the real-rooted sub-polynomials (RRSPs) whose terms are chosen from those of $f(x)$.
(This partial answer only finds an upper bound, shown in $(3)$, on the count, and I have only conjectured a family of polynomials attaining the bound. However, if the quoted Hutchinson result for power series actually applies to polynomials, it effectively characterizes polynomials attaining the bound.)
Note that a polynomial with non-negative coefficients has no positive roots. So, the roots of any real-rooted sub-polynomial $g(x)$ must be negative or zero; thus such a polynomial has the form $a x^p \prod_{k=0}^{q-1}(x+r_k)$, for strictly positive $r_k$ (the negatives of the negative roots). Expanding the product, there's no chance of cancellation, so $g(x)$ has a term for each power of $x$ from $p$ to $p+q$, no skips; therefore, as a sub-polynomial of $f(x)$, any real-rooted $g(x)$ has the form
$$\sum_{k=p}^{p+q}a_k x^k \qquad p\in\{0,\ldots,n\}, q\in\{0,\ldots,n-p\} \tag2$$
I call these consecutive-term sub-polynomials (CTSPs) of $f(x)$. Also, abusing terminology, I'll call a three-term CTSP "quadratic" (effectively ignoring any power-of-$x$ factor), as the term is more evocative of its nature; likewise, I'll call a four-, two-, or one-term CTSP "cubic", "linear", or "constant".
Including $(p,q)=(0,n)$ (ie, the original polynomial $f(x)$), and $(p,q)=(0,0)$ (the constant polynomial $g(x)=a_0$) the total number of CTSPs of a degree-$n$ polynomial is the triangular number
$$\tfrac12(n+1)(n+2) \tag3$$
Any RRSP is necessarily a CTSP, but the converse is not true. Trivially (and by convention for the constant polynomial $g(x)=a_0$), any constant or linear (one- or two-term) CTSP is an RRSP; thus, a lower bound on the RRSPs of $f(x)$ (including $f(x)$ itself is $(n+1)+(n)+(1)=2(n+1)$. After that, there are no guarantees. For example, all CTSPs of $x^3+4x^2+4x+1$ are real-rooted; however, as  observed by @GregMartin, $x^3+4x^2+4x+c$ is real-rooted for $1<c\leq 32/27$, but its quadratic CTSP $4x^2+4x+c$ is not. Therefore, $(3)$ is an upper bound on the number of RRSPs of $f(x)$.
Exactly counting RRSPs spawned a given polynomial without examining all of the CCSPs seems a daunting task. A more-manageable preliminary one may be to find conditions under which the count attains the upper bound, as with these quartics:
$$
x^4+\phantom{0}8x^3+\phantom{0}16x^2+\phantom{00}8x+\phantom{00}1 \\
x^4+43x^3+293x^2+477x+192 \\
x^4+37x^3+299x^2+590x+271$$
As it happens, quadratic CTSPs are not just the first obstacles to "full real-rooted-ness", they're the only obstacles. Consider this result from J. L. Hutchinson's 1923 AMS article "On a Remarkable Class of Entire Functions" (PDF link via ams.org):

[Theorem "A", pg 327] Consider $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kz^k$ with positive coefficients $a_k>0$ so that $$\frac{a_k^2}{a_{k-1}a_{k+1}} \geq 4 \tag{$\star$}$$
for all $k\geq1$. Then this is equivalent to:

the zeros of $f(z)$ are all simple, real, negative, and
the zeros of the partial sum polynomials $\sum_{M\le k\le N}a_kz^k, M<N$ are all real, and $\le 0$


(The above taken from a restatement by @dan_fulea in this Math.SE answer, avoiding reference to Hutchinson's auxiliary values $b_k$.)
Note that $(\star)$ is precisely the condition that the discriminant of each quadratic CTSP (ignoring multiplied powers of $x$) is non-negative, making each such CTSP real-rooted. Consequently, once the quadratics are determined to be real-rooted, Hutchinson effectively asserts: It's real roots all the way up (and down)!
Note also that, as written, Hutchinson's result concerns power series, all of whose infinitely-many coefficients are strictly-positive. As @WillSawin points out in a comment, we can readily leverage this result in our context: simply use $(\star)$ to extend our polynomial $f(x)$ to a power series via $a_k=\dfrac{a^2_{k-1}}{4a_{k-2}}$ for $k>n$.
Thus, Hutchinson has provided a delightfully-elementary characterization of "fully real-rooted" polynomials.

I'll conclude with a result I initially floated as a conjecture, which uses the solution to the recurrence $a_k=\dfrac{a^2_{k-1}}{4a_{k-2}}$ (with $a_0=1, a_1=a$) throughout:

All CTSPs of $\;\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{ax}{2^{k-1}}\right)^{k}\;$, with $a>0$, are real-rooted.

In particular, taking $a=2^{n-1}$, so that $a_k=2^{k(n-k)}$, gives a palindromic polynomial with this property; eg, $x^3+4x^2+4x+1$ and $x^4+8x^3+16x^2+8x+1$ mentioned earlier.
Note. This Math.SE question indicates that the real-rootedness of the palindromic polynomial is the subject of Putnam 2014, Problem B4. (I found the pointer to the Putnam question amid the comments to @mick's recent question (referenced in the answer below), which contain additional discussion that may be helpful.)

@RishwanthSV Thank you for setting the bounty.

@mick's answer redirect to another answer that mention a theorem from Hutchinson which proves your conjecture!

@Nolord: Curiously (and embarrassingly), I looked at that question but somehow overlooked the Hutchison result. It incorporates a natural generalization I'd considered but lacked evidence or confidence to suggest in my Conjecture: making the discriminants of the (quadratic factors of) the three-term CTSPs non-negative, instead of simply zero. ... Anyway, since Hutchison's result fully characterizes polynomials all of whose CTSPs are RRSPs, much of my discussion becomes moot. I'll make appropriate adjustments to my answer when I get some time. ... Thanks for the heads-up! :)

Hutchinson's result transfers to power series, even taking its proof as a black box: Given a sequence $a_0,\dots, a_n$ with $a_k^2 \geq 4 a_{k-1} a_{k+1}$ for all $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$, we can easily extend to an infinite sequence $a_0,a_1,.\dots$ satisfying the equation for all $k$: Just define $a_{k+1} = a_{k}^2/4 a_{k-1}$ for all $k \geq n$. Then by Hutchinson's theorem all polynomial subsequences are real-rooted. The converse is easy since as you note Hutchinson's criterion is equivalent to real rootedness of length 3 subsequences.

@WillSawin: Well, there it is. Thanks! :)

Just a comment
$A(z) = 1 + z  + z^2/3! + z^3/6! + z^4/10! + z^5/15! + z^6/21! + z^7/28! + ...$
and
$t(z) = 1 + z  + z^2/(2!)^2 + z^3/(4!)^2 + z^4/(7!)^2 + z^5/(11!)^2 + z^6/(16!)^2 + z^7/(22!)^2 + ...$
both seem to have the property that any polynomial formed by their resp.terms only has real zero's.
I found these polynomials at
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/special-polynomials
But at the moment I have no idea how to prove it.
However I asked a related question and got an answer that might help us both :
$1 + z + \frac{z^2}{4} + \frac{z^3}{4^3} + \frac{z^4}{4^6} + \frac{z^5}{4^{10}} +... = 0$ implies $Im(z) = 0$?

Some results from this answer are already in Blue's  answer.
Following it, we shall call a polynomial real-rooted, if each its root is real.
We assume that the coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_n$ of the real-rooted polynomial $f(x)$ are nonnegative and we have to detect real-rooted subpolynomials $g(x)$ of $f(x)$. Unfortunately, below we shall see that  although we can provide some simple necessary and sufficient conditions when $g(x)$ is real-rooted, I  expect that the exact conditions in the general case are cumbersome.
Anyway, let us go ahead. To skip the trivial case we assume that $g(x)=x^ph(x)$, where $h(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial and $h(0)>0$. Since all coefficients of $h(x)$ are nonnegative, $h(x)$ has only negative roots, say $-r_1,\dots,-r_q$. Then $h(x)=a\prod_{k=1}^q x+r_k$ for some $a>0$. Expanding the product, we see that all coefficients of $h(x)$ are positive. In particular, when $g(x)=f(x)$ then $p=0$ and we see that the coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_n$ of $f(x)$ are positive. We shall formulate our conditions
in terms of the numbers $b_k=\frac{a_k^2}{a_{k-1}a_{k+1}}$ for each positive integer $k<n$.
Thus $g(x)=\sum_{k=p}^{p+q} a_kx^k$. Moreover, according to the product expansion, for each nonnegative integer $k\le q$ we have
$a_{p+k}=a_{p+q}E_{q-k}$, where $E_{q-k}=e_{q-k}(r_0,\dots,r_{q-1})$ and $e_{q-k}$ is the $(q-k)$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $q$ variables. By Newton's inequalities, if
$0<q-k<q$ (that is, $0<k<q$) then $$\frac{E_{q-k-1}}{q \choose q-k-1}\cdot \frac{E_{q-k+1}}{q \choose q-k+1}\le
\left(\frac{E_{q-k}}{q \choose q-k}\right)^2,$$
so $$b_{p+k}=\frac{a_{p+k}^2}{a_{p+k-1}a_{p+k+1}}=\frac{E_{q-k}^2}{E_{q-k-1}\cdot E_{q-k+11}}\ge
\frac{{q\choose q-k}^2}{{q \choose q-k-1}{q \choose q-k+1}}=$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac{q!}{(q-k)!k!}\right)^2}{\frac{q!}{(q-k-1)!(k+1)!}\cdot {\frac{q!}{(q-k+1)!(k-1)!}}}=
\frac{(q-k-1)!(k+1)!(q-k+1)!(k-1)!}{((q-k)!k!)^2}=$$
$$\left(1+\frac 1k\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac 1{q-k}\right).$$
Denote the latter number by $N_{q,k}$.
The above inequalities suggest the question whether the condition $b_{p+k}\ge N_{q,k}$ holding for each positive $k<q$  ensure that the sub-polynomial $g(x)$ is real-rooted. The answer is affirmative when $q=2$, because in this case the only condition is equivalent to the nonnegativity of the discriminant of $g(x)$. Moreover, as far as I understood Blue's answer, the sub-polynomial $g(x)$ is real-rooted provided
$b_{p+k}\ge 4$ for each positive $k<q$; then each chain $b_p,...,b_{p+q}$ whose members are at least $4$ provides $\frac 12 q(q+1)$ real-rooted sub-polynomials of $f(x)$.
But already for $q=3$ we need more refined conditions to ensure that $g(x)$ is real-rooted. Indeed, in this case $N_{3,1}=N_{3,2}=3$. The cubic factor $h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^q a_{p+k}x^k$ of $g(x)$ is real-rooted iff its discriminant
$$a_{p+2}^2a_{p+1}^2-4a_{p+3}a_{p+1}^3-4a_{p+2}^3a_p-27a_{p+3}^2a_p^2+18a_{p+3}a_{p+2}a_{p+1}a_p\ge 0,$$
that is when
$$b_{p+2}^2b_{p+1}^2-4b_{p+2}b_{p+1}^2-4b_{p+2}^2b_{b+1}+18b_{p+2}b_{p+1}\ge 27.$$
But the latter inequality fails when $b_{p+1}=3$ and $b_{p+2}=4$.
For $q=4$ the expression of the discriminant is cumbersome. Moreover, the nonnegativity of the discriminant of a polynomial $h(x)$ of degree $4$
is a necessary (but, in general not a sufficient) condition for the real-rootedness $h(x)$.
